# Failed to connect Tor 3.5.2 on Windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, bridge, pluggable-transports

I am unable to connect to Tor recently. I have got following log:

```
25-02-2014 20:53:08 PM.370 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.  
25-02-2014 20:53:08 PM.370 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  
25-02-2014 20:53:08 PM.710 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop.  
25-02-2014 21:03:23 PM.509 [NOTICE] Our directory information is no longer up-to-date enough to build circuits: We have no usable consensus.  
25-02-2014 21:05:36 PM.401 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 5; recommendation warn)  
25-02-2014 21:05:36 PM.402 [WARN] 5 connections have failed:  
25-02-2014 21:05:36 PM.402 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE  
25-02-2014 21:05:36 PM.402 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)  
25-02-2014 21:05:36 PM.403 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE
```

Its just fails to connect after showing Finishing Handshake with first Hop.
What could be the problem ?
Any help is appreciated.
I am using Browser Bundle on Windows.

After using Bridges with Tor 2.3.25, I get:

```
Feb 25 21:58:50.870 [Notice] Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-17c24b3118224d65) running on Windows 7.  
Feb 25 21:58:50.870 [Notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning  
Feb 25 21:58:50.870 [Notice] Read configuration file "E:\Misc\Tor Old\Data\Tor\torrc".  
Feb 25 21:58:50.871 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.21-stable using method win32. Good.  
Feb 25 21:58:50.871 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  
Feb 25 21:58:50.871 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151  
Feb 25 21:58:50.871 [Notice] Parsing GEOIP file .\Data\Tor\geoip.  
Feb 25 21:58:56.030 [Notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.  
Feb 25 21:58:56.032 [Notice] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 0:00 hours, with 2 circuits open. I've sent 0 kB and received 0 kB.  
Feb 25 21:58:56.454 [Notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server.  
Feb 25 21:59:57.855 [Warning] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 2; recommendation warn)  
Feb 25 21:59:57.856 [Warning] 2 connections have failed:  
Feb 25 21:59:57.856 [Warning] 1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)  
Feb 25 21:59:57.856 [Warning] 1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
```