# Failed to connect to Tor network?

Tags: configuration, windows, help, bridge, browsers

I tried connecting to the Tor network. Each time it stops at ***Loading Network Status*** .

This is the log file:

```
27-05-2015 10:54:40.877 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27-05-2015 10:54:42.573 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27-05-2015 10:54:48.838 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
27-05-2015 10:54:48.839 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
27-05-2015 10:54:49.225 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27-05-2015 10:54:49.234 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27-05-2015 10:54:53.143 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
27-05-2015 10:54:53.770 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
27-05-2015 10:54:54.442 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
27-05-2015 10:54:56.247 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (fresh): $AF9F66B7B04F8FF6F32D455F05135250A16543C9~Unnamed at 169.229.59.75 
27-05-2015 10:54:56.248 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27-05-2015 10:55:01.356 [WARN] Our clock is 17 hours, 4 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-05-28 03:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
27-05-2015 10:55:01.357 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
27-05-2015 10:55:25.925 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27-05-2015 10:55:25.925 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27-05-2015 10:55:25.925 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27-05-2015 10:55:26.814 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to connect Tor 3.5.2 on Windows](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/failed-to-connect-tor-3-5-2-on-windows)

Comment: When you say you "can't access anything", what have you tried to access? Are you able to access websites without using Tor - i.e. do you have any connectivity at all? (Don't try this if it's going to compromise you in any way... )

Comment: time is set correctly. But still it is stuck at: "establishing an encrypted directory connection"
also tried bridges please help

Answer (score 6):

It is repeatedly warning you about the time being wrong. A synchronized clock is extremely important to make a connection to anything even if you've been able to download all of the consensus information.

```
7/8/2015 6:49:43 AM.695 [WARN] Our clock is 1 hours, 10 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-07-08 08:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
```

Fix your clock so that it has accurate time in an appropriate timezone (e.g. UTC). If you're using a virtual machine, consider different ways of making sure the clock has synced. Otherwise you'll just have to manually fix it each time.

Answer (score 5):

The first warning in the logs is this:

```
11/6/2015 7:05:53 AM.400 [WARN] Our clock is 1 days, 21 hours, 54 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-11-08 10:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!
```

So this is currently your main problem:

**Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!**

[This](http://vancouver-webpages.com/time/) page is a good resource for understanding how accurate your machine's clock is.

Answer (score 3):

This line if very descriptive:

> 27-05-2015 10:55:01.356 [WARN] Our clock is 17 hours, 4 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2015-05-28 03:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. **Please check your time and date settings!**

Your clock is not correct. Make sure that you've set your clock and your timezone to be appropriate.