# Not Able To Connect To Tor {Arch Linux}

Tags: linux

I need to connect to tor. So I downloaded tor doing:

```
sudo pacman -S tor torsocks
```

it downloaded succesfully:

```
Total Installed Size:  7.51 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(2/2) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
(2/2) checking package integrity                   [######################] 100%
(2/2) loading package files                        [######################] 100%
(2/2) checking for file conflicts                  [######################] 100%
(2/2) checking available disk space                [######################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/2) installing tor                               [######################] 100%
error: command failed to execute correctly
Optional dependencies for tor
    torsocks: for torify [pending]
(2/2) installing torsocks                          [######################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Updating manpage index...
```

When I run the service on the other hand:

```
[coleton@coleton ~]$ sudo systemctl start tor
[coleton@coleton ~]$ sudo systemctl status tor.service
● tor.service - Anonymizing Overlay Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-26 18:16:05 UTC; 8min ago
 Main PID: 17112 (tor)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
           └─17112 /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc

Jun 26 18:16:09 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server 
Jun 26 18:16:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key cert
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server 
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Our clock is 3 hours, 43 minutes behind the 
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:17:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:18:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:19:11 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:24:15 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
lines 1-18/18 (END)...skipping...
● tor.service - Anonymizing Overlay Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-26 18:16:05 UTC; 8min ago
 Main PID: 17112 (tor)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
           └─17112 /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc

Jun 26 18:16:09 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server '131.188.40.189:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate
Jun 26 18:16:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Our clock is 3 hours, 43 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-06-26 22:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly.
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:17:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:18:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:19:11 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:24:15 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

The error (Which I think it's this):

```
Our clock is 3 hours, 43 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-06-26 22:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly.
```

The error is weird because my clock is in fact set correctly.
Any Idea Guys?

P.S Following this guide:
[Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3MvgF36I2U)

EDIT:
I followed [@canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize) but got this error:

```
[coleton@coleton ~]$ sudo systemctl status tor.service
● tor.service - Anonymizing Overlay Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-26 18:16:05 UTC; 4h 13min left
 Main PID: 17112 (tor)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
           └─17112 /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc

Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key cert
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server 
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Our clock is 3 hours, 43 minutes behind the 
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:17:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:18:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:19:11 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:24:15 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 18:34:26 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, b
Jun 26 14:00:01 coleton Tor[17112]: Your system clock just jumped 18067 seconds 
lines 1-18/18 (END)...skipping...
● tor.service - Anonymizing Overlay Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-06-26 18:16:05 UTC; 4h 13min left
 Main PID: 17112 (tor)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
           └─17112 /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc

Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: Our clock is 3 hours, 43 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-06-26 22:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly.
Jun 26 18:16:10 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:17:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:18:09 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:19:11 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:24:15 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 18:34:26 coleton Tor[17112]: I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus.
Jun 26 14:00:01 coleton Tor[17112]: Your system clock just jumped 18067 seconds backward; assuming established circuits no longer work.
```

Comment: No. This is way different. Different errors, different Operating System, and has nothing to do with time. Please don't report my post just because your mad.

Comment: You have told your system it is in UTC time, you set the time accurately as per localtime. Localtime is, however, not UTC time therefor your time is wrong. This is exactly the same problem with exactly the same answer. Check your date and time settings.

Comment: Set it to UTC time same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking around other *simaler* questions, [this one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/failed-to-connect-to-tor-network) was it. But it was actually a site that helped not any answers in the question. [This site](http://vancouver-webpages.com/time/) showed me my true local time. Then I converted it to millatary time. Then it worked. Doing the command:

```
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

does not work and is a waste of time in my case. But using the above site to do it for you.

Comment: after setting a UTC time zone you **must** do `ntpdate` to set time and reboot then. That's how it works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with time on your PC. For a fail-safe setup use UTC timezone and NTP to sync your time: local timezones are *rarely* causing this problem even being selected correctly: if the PC has an old TZ definition and it's changed(from GMT+3 to GMT+4 for example) or vice versa(if you have a new TZ definition but servers still have old). NTP time sync is essential, and - by the way - you can use a cheap GPS module to obtain a precise timing

Comment: I've already solved the problem xD