# Loading relay information failed (connection timeout - 109.163.234.9:443)

Tags: error

on Debian wheezy only tor version version 6.5 will connect. All newer versions will not connect, with bridges, obfuscated or any other way. Error log as follows:

```
10/08/2017 16:16:46.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2017 16:16:46.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2017 16:16:46.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2017 16:16:46.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/08/2017 16:16:46.700 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/home/user/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
10/08/2017 16:16:47.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
10/08/2017 16:16:47.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
10/08/2017 16:16:47.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
10/08/2017 16:16:48.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
10/08/2017 16:16:48.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
10/08/2017 16:16:52.800 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:131.188.40.189:443): It seems that our clock is ahead by 7 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is behind. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
10/08/2017 16:16:52.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
10/08/2017 16:17:05.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
10/08/2017 16:17:05.900 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:131.188.40.189:443): It seems that our clock is ahead by 7 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is behind. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
10/08/2017 16:17:05.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
10/08/2017 16:17:05.900 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6709, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path bw.) 
10/08/2017 16:17:06.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors 
10/08/2017 16:17:06.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6709, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path bw.) 
10/08/2017 16:18:10.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 50%: Loading relay descriptors. (Connection timed out; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host ABF7FBF389C9A747938B639B20E80620B460B2A9 at 109.163.234.9:443) 
10/08/2017 16:18:10.600 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
10/08/2017 16:18:10.600 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 50%: Loading relay descriptors. (Connection timed out; TIMEOUT; count 11; recommendation warn; host 587E0A9552E4274B251F29B5B2673D38442EE4BF at 95.130.12.119:443) 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 50%: Loading relay descriptors. (Connection timed out; TIMEOUT; count 12; recommendation warn; host 8672E8A01B4D3FA4C0BBE21C740D4506302EA487 at 188.166.23.127:443) 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [WARN]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
10/08/2017 16:18:46.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/failed-to-connect-to-tor-network)

Comment: This has not been answered yet, no explanation why v6.5 works but not the newer versions and no help in any case is available anywhere for this error.

Comment: Fix your date and time, they are incorrect. 6.5 maybe works because it has already bootstrapped and has a working consensus.

Comment: removing .tor/ directory worked for me, using tor package with Bridges on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please tell me you guys were able to figure it out I’m going crazy here I’ve been trying to access tor all day literally since I woke up tell me you guys can help man Ik desperate

Answer (score 2):

```
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data
```

worked for me on macOS.

As noted on [torproject.org](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)

> DataDirectory DIR
>
> Store working data in DIR. Can not be changed while tor is running.
>   (Default: ~/.tor if your home directory is not /; otherwise,
>   @LOCALSTATEDIR@/lib/tor. On Windows, the default is your
>   ApplicationData folder.)

So on Linux one of the following might work;

```
rm -r ~/.tor
rm -r ~/.tor-browser-en
rm -r /usr/local/var/lib/tor
```

Comment: None of the above are directories that Tor Browser uses under Linux, as stated on the previous comment: All of the data accesses that Tor makes are to directories *inside* the folder where Tor Browser was extracted.

Answer (score 0):

@user1133275  me too!

rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data

working