# cannot connect to TOR because of wrong time

Tags: windows

been having trouble getting on TOR, it gives me this log

```
3/11/2017 17:45:43.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/11/2017 17:45:43.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/11/2017 17:45:43.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/11/2017 17:45:43.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.400 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:194.109.206.212:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 53 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
3/11/2017 17:45:44.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
3/11/2017 17:45:50.800 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:46:02.700 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:199.58.81.140:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:46:35.800 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:128.31.0.34:9101): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:46:36.100 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:128.31.0.34:9101): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:47:46.500 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:193.23.244.244:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
3/11/2017 17:48:48.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/11/2017 17:48:48.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/11/2017 17:48:48.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/11/2017 17:48:49.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

i have rebooted my pc several times and adjusting my time doesn't work either

Comment: `3/11/2017 ... our clock is behind by 3 days, 22 hours, 52 minutes ...` your time is drastically wrong, it is off by *days*. You need to set the correct *date*, *time* and *timezone*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/failed-to-connect-to-tor-network)

Comment: https://www.guidingtech.com/3119/windows-clock-sync/

Answer (score 2):

Well, the core of the readon is a clock and date, but the reason can be:

- You are really having wrong time on your PC. If it's windows - set it and the timezone in Control Panel, if it's unix-like - set the timezone **first** and the date+time next.
- You're experiencing an NTP fake attack, here in Russia some ISP's do this stuff to disrupt Tor and torrent users. Here is the trick: they do announce an NTP server of them as *stratum 0* and, due to the very fast connection to it via ISP's network - they can skew the clocks just sending a bad data over the network. It hit my router once, and I was pretty surprised with `ntpq` and `tcpdump` output... The "cure" is to have an NTP server of yours with strict IP filtering for input and use *your* NTP server to sync all your time. It's rare, but 5 cases in 3 cities were in my recent practice.

Answer (score 0):

`man timedatectl` if on systemd-linux

`apt/yum install ntp/ntpd` if not

If windows... click on the clock or something, choose sync time something