# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection "Loading network status failed"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install

```
1/29/2018 2:14:22 AM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/29/2018 2:14:22 AM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/29/2018 2:14:22 AM.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/29/2018 2:14:23 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
1/29/2018 2:14:23 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
1/29/2018 2:14:24 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
1/29/2018 2:14:24 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
1/29/2018 2:14:25 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [WARN] Received NETINFO cell with skewed time (OR:154.35.175.225:443): It seems that our clock is behind by 8 hours, 59 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Clock skew -32388 in NETINFO cell from OR; CLOCK_SKEW; count 2; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443) 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
1/29/2018 2:14:30 AM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/failed-to-connect-to-tor-network)

Answer (score 3):

Your clock is wrong. Tor requires an accurate time, date, and **timezone** to work.

Given that your time is almost exactly 9 hours off, most likely the time on your computer **looks** correct, but you have incorrectly configured your timezone. Set the timezone correctly. This will most likely screw up the time. Fix the time after the timezone is correct.